# Terminated due to signal 9

Tags: ios, flutter, apple-watch

I have a fully functional Flutter app which runs well on IOS.

I am developing a companion Apple Watch app. The watch app will read the user heartbeat and therefore needs the NSHealthShareUsageDescription & NSHealthUpdateUsageDescription permissions.

To debug, I first run the Flutter app from XCode.  2nd I run the Watch app from XCode.  When the Watch app begins execution, the Flutter app is terminated with "Terminated due to signal 9".

This happens with even a simple "Hello world" watch app that does not access the HealthKit.

If the app is run from VSCode, when the watch app is run from XCode, the IOS app terminates with:

```
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = signal SIGKILL
    frame #0: 0x00000001d9f88da8 libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg2_trap + 8
libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg2_trap:
->  0x1d9f88da8 <+8>: ret
libsystem_kernel.dylib`macx_swapon:
    0x1d9f88dac <+0>: mov    x16, #-0x30
    0x1d9f88db0 <+4>: svc    #0x80
    0x1d9f88db4 <+8>: ret
Target 0: (Runner) stopped.
Lost connection to device.
```

Any help/advice on this greatly appreciated.